# Pugjs in php file

Tags: php, pug

I am trying to use pugjs code and files in php files immediately instead of converting them first to html then including the html in the php file.
Is there a way to do so?

I have tried phug template but when I use it and follow GitHub's instructions it says "phug class not found".

```
Phug :: display( p= $var , $var = value )
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. Try including minimally valid source code, or links thereto, and the complete error log.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `Phug` using composer (or another method, like downloading it).

`composer require pug-php/pug:"^3.0"`

See [the docs](https://www.phug-lang.com/#in-your-favorite-framework) for more details.